# Как сравнить два значения внутри html страницы

Tags: javascript, html, ejs, fullcalendar

Нужно стравнить два значения внутри страницы html.
С помощью EJS я знаю какой пользователь залогинился на странице:

```
<%= currentUser.userLink %>
```

Также, JS скрипт указывает в каком месте списка на странице ткнул пользователь, и передает эти данные в input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="userLink" name="event[userLink]">
```

И теперь мне нужно сравнить два эти значения внутри html страницы и далее логика согласно результата сравнения. Условно говоря типа такого:

```
<% if (<%= currentUser.userLink %> == <input type="hidden" id="userLink" name="event[userLink]">){
       do something(например показать пользователю модальное окно)}else{(ничего не показать)}; %>
```

Заранее спасибо.
//================= Part 2 ==================//
Попробую объяснить процесс подробнее:
Все происходит вокруг JS библиотеки Fullcalendar.
Календарь `scheduler.ejs` рендериться с помощью Express:

```
    // render scheduler page
    router.get('/scheduler', isLoggedIn, (req,res) => {
        //create personnel list and send it to scheduler page
        Resource.find({ 'group': 'Personnel' },'title', function  (err, personnelList) 
            {if (err) throw err;
            res.render('scheduler', {personnelList: personnelList, currentUser: req.user})
        });
    });
```

На страницу сразу передается информация о пользователе, который в данный момент залогинился.
2. На календаре есть поле `resources`, где перечислены сотрудники. Есть JS файл настроек календаря (если я правильно понимаю это на стороне клиента). В этом файле есть `render hook` с помощью которого можно получить информацию о поле в которое ткнул пользователь:

```
//resource hook
resourceLabelDidMount: function(arg) {
  arg.el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      //hook to personnel labels (add personal events)
      if (arg.resource.extendedProps.group == 'Personnel'){
        $('#personalEvent').modal('show');
        document.getElementById('resourceId').value = arg.resource.id;
        document.getElementById('userLink').value = arg.resource.extendedProps.userLink;
      //hook project lables (add services)
      } else if (arg.resource.extendedProps.group !== undefined) {
        $('#addService').modal('show');
        document.getElementById('parentId').value = arg.resource.id;
      //hook to service labels (add job events)
      } else {
        $('#jobEvent').modal('show');
        document.getElementById('resourceId2').value = arg.resource.id;
        document.getElementById('projectId').value = arg.resource._resource.parentId;
        };
      });
},
```

То есть можно узнать на какую фамилию ткнул пользователь (`userLink`).
3. Это значение я передаю на страницу календаря в тэг `input`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="userLink" name="event[userLink]">
```

4.Теперь на странице есть данные о пользователе, который залогинился `<%= currentUser.userLink %>` и есть информация о тот в кого из списка ткнул пользователь `<input type="hidden" id="userLink" name="event[userLink]">`. Я могу их увидеть если например вывести так:

```
<input type="hidden" id="userLink" name="event[userLink]">
```

5.В этом же файле `scheduler.ejs` есть модальное окно, которое позволяет пользователю добавлять личное событие в календарь (отпуск к примеру).

```
<!-- Add Personal Event -->
<div id="personalEvent" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Personal Event</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="/scheduler/personalEvent" method="POST">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="personalEvent" class="col-form-label">Personal Event:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="personalEvent" name="event[title]">
            <input type="hidden" id="resourceId" name="event[resourceId]">
            <input type="hidden" id="userLink" name="event[userLink]">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
                      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="eventStart" name="event[start]">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="eventEnd" name="event[end]">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Save Event</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

6.В данный момент это окно открывается вне зависимости от кого на какую фамилию кликнул пользователь. А я бы хотел сделать так чтобы окно открывалось только если пользователь кликнул на своей фамилию в списке. То есть чтобы перед открытием модального окна происходило сравнение `<%= currentUser.userLink %>` и значения из  `<input type="hidden" id="userLink" name="event[userLink]">`.

Comment: Немного непонятно, что вам надо. В какой момент надо сравнивать?

Comment: Степан, спасибо что откликнулись. Я добавил более подробное описание в вопросе (Part 2)

Comment: Стало более понятно. Каким образом открывается модальное окно?

Comment: Окно открывается по команде из `resource hook` (пункт второй в вопросе) `$('#personalEvent').modal('show');`

Comment: Ага, вижу. И последний уточняющий вопрос - куда в html записывается `<%= currentUser.userLink %>`. В какой-то `input`?

Comment: я пока его никуда не записывал. просто вывел на страницу чтобы видеть что он есть. в принципе для него можно input создать, например: `<input type="hidden" name="currentUser" value="<%= currentUser.userLink %>">`

Comment: Я немного изменил ответ, проверьте сейчас.

Comment: Проверил. Ругается `Cannot access 'currentUser' before initialization` Пробовал ставить и перед инпутом и после и вне модала - везде эта ошибка.

Comment: Что-то вы не так поменяли. Покажите код, который у вас сейчас есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если создать

```
<input type="hidden" id="currentUser" value="<%= currentUser.userLink %>">
```

То потом в блоке кода, где у вас вызывается модальное окно можно написать:

```
// Получаем значение из инпута с id=currentUser значение
const currentUser = document.querySelector('#currentUser').value;
// Если значения равны - вызываем модальное окно
if(arg.resource.extendedProps.userLink === currentUser){
  $('#personalEvent').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Заработало!!! Сделал как вы предложили. Теперь все отлично работает. Заодно убрал кучу лишнего кода. Огромное спасибо за помощь!